# Sentiment Analysis: Is there a way to extract positive and negative aspects in reviews?

Tags: nlp, sentiment-analysis

Currently, I'm working on a project where I need to extract the relevant aspects used in positive and negative reviews in real time.

For the notions of more negative and positive, it will be a question of contextualizing the word. Distinguish between a word that sounds positive in a negative context (consider irony).

Here is an example:
*Very nice welcome!!! We ate very well with traditional dishes as at home, the quality but also the quantity are in appointment!!!**

**Positive aspects:** welcome, traditional dishes, quality, quantity

Can anyone suggest to me some tutorials, papers or ideas about this topic?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This task is called **Aspect Based Sentiment Analysis** (ABSA). Most popular is the format and dataset specified in the [2014 Semantic Evaluation Workshop (Task 5)](https://alt.qcri.org/semeval2016/task5/) and its updated versions in the following years.

Overview of model efficiencies over the years:

https://paperswithcode.com/sota/aspect-based-sentiment-analysis-on-semeval

Good source for ressources and repositories on the topic (some are very advanced but there are some more starter friendly ressources in there too):

https://github.com/ZhengZixiang/ABSAPapers

Just from my general experience in this topic a very powerful starting point that doesn't require advanced knowledge in machine learning model design is to prepare a Dataset (such as the one provided for the SemEval2014 Task) that is in a [Token Classification](https://huggingface.co/tasks/token-classification) Format and use it to fine-tune a pretrained transformer model such as BERT, RoBERTa or similar. Check out any tutorial on how to do fine-tuning on a token classification model like [this one in huggingface](https://huggingface.co/course/chapter7/2?fw=pt). They usually use the popular task of Named Entity Recognition (NER) as the example task but for the ABSA-Task you basically do the same thing but with other labels and a different dataset.

Obviously an even easier approach would be to take more rule-based approaches or combine a rule-based approach with a trained sentiment analysis model/negation detection etc., but I think generally with a rule-based approach you can expect a much inferior performance compared to using state-of-the-art models as transformers.

If you want to go even more advanced than just fine-tuning the pretrained transformer models then check out the second and third link I provided and look at some of the machine learning model designs specifically designed for Aspect Based Sentiment Analysis.